# Have apache choose a php version based on the extension in the url, but with a single file on the filesystem

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I want to configure a local apache server to serve php files with different php versions. In my document root I have `phpinfo.php`, now if I go to `http://localhost/phpinfo.php4`, I want to see the phpinfo.php file processed with php4, if I go to `http://localhost/phpinfo.php5` I want to see the same file processed with php5.

Note: both php 4 and 5 are already installed side by side, I have no problem configuring apache to treat files that have a `.php4` or `.php5` extension *on the filesystem* with the correct php version. What I want is for apache to do the following:

- If the url-path ends in `.php5`, serve the file which has a `.php` extension on the filesystem using the `application/x-httpd-php5` handler.
- If the url-path ends in `.php4`, serve the same file with the `.php` extension on the filesystem using the `application/x-httpd-php4` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of trial & error I figured it out. The magic incantations are

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php5$ $1.php [H=application/x-httpd-php,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php4$ $1.php  [H=php4,PT]
```

where `application/x-httpd-php` is the default handler that mod_php5 registers, and `php4` is a custom cgi handler that calls php4. The part I had most trouble figuring out is the `PT` (passthrough) flag, which is necessary for cgi handlers to work. PT causes other modules that do url rewriting to also do their job, and mod_cgi is such a module.